# Which characters can themselves get to the Hanamura Point B right-side ledge?

Tags: overwatch

In Hanamura there's a "ledge" above the right-hand side of Point B. Some characters can get up there themselves whether they're on attack or defense. If you have time between waves, Mei can use a wall to get defenders up there.

Based on my playing around, I've been able to get up there with the following characters:

- Genji (wall climb)
- Pharrah
- Reaper (teleport)
- Hanzo (wall climb)
- Junkrat (landmine)
- Mei (build a wall under myself next to it)
- Widowmaker (grapple)
- D.Va
- Winston
- Mercy (leaping to ally)

(I wasn't able to get up there with Lucio wall ride, but I suspect it's possible).

Any other characters or tricks that I've missed?

[image: Hanamura ledge]

Comment: Basically everyone can get there with Mei's wall...

Comment: Haven't tried it but I would suspect Winston would be able to as well.

Comment: @Virusbomb oops, I actually tried that too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heroes that can get to the sniping ledge on Point B are:

> Genji, Pharah, Reaper (teleport), Sombra, Tracer, Hanzo, Junkrat, Mei
>   (ice wall), Widowmaker (grappling hook), D.Va, Winston, Zarya
>   (propelling herself with the alternate fire) and Lucio.

Hopefully that explains your question.

Comment: Ah, I could't get up there with Zarya, but good to know it's possible!

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't think Junkrat can get up there without the like perfect mine-- it seems too high. Maybe Sombra can?

Comment: I Junkrat mined up there 5/5 from both the low ground and the high ground on the left, so I think that's ok. I'm excited for Sombra too!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Tracer is able to access it using mid-air teleports, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: This sort of short answer, that doesn't really answer the question, but still does add value should be added as a comment, rather than an answer.